# String query with binary indexed tree

Tags: c++, segment-tree, fenwick-tree, binary-indexed-tree

I want to range query a string using Fenwick tree. But something is going wrong with my code. 
Concatenation is giving error
Eror is:[Error] no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::vector >' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}')
  Given a string s, I want to store the string in this fenwick tree.
e.g. s=abcdef, on BIT it should like(top-bottom) a ab-c abcd-e abcd-ef
[Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkpXh.png)

```
vector<string> BIT[100005];
    int n;
    void BI(int x,string c)
    {
        for(;x<=n;x+=x&-x)  
        {
            BIT[x]+=c;
        }

    }

    int main()
    {
        cin>>n;
        string s;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {   cin>>s;
            BI(i,s);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what data this is processing, nor what the output should be.

Comment: e.g. s=abcdef, on BIT it should like(up-bottom) a ab-c abcd-e abcd-ef

Comment: Isn't `std::vector<x> y[n]` a C-style array of vectors? Why not a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`?

Comment: Don't understand your tree formatting. You mean "top to bottom," right? But what are the spaces and what are the dashes? Can you write in heap format, _e.g._ a, ab, c, abcd, null, null, e, etc.

Comment: spaces is between two consecutive depths and dashes meant parent-child

Comment: I have included the image

Comment: `But something is going wrong with my code.` What? Where? Don't just post _'it doesn't work'_ without explaining what specifically is wrong.

Comment: problem is with concatenation step BIT[x]+=c;

Comment: @nRT - I have explained why in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
vector<string> BIT[100005];
```

and this

```
BIT[x]+=c;
```

don't go together. You have an array of vectors of strings (2-dimensional matrix, basically). And you are trying to add string `c` to a vector at `BIT[x]`. Your compile errors should be telling you this.

You probably did not mean to make an array of vector of strings. To make a vector of strings with size 100005, do this:

```
vector<string> BIT(100005);
```

*i.e.* parentheses, not square brackets.